# Inferring types of deeply nested object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, lookup, type-inference

I'm trying to create a function that safely looks up the property in deeply nested object (`theme` in this case). I should mention that I don't want to statically define its type because they are intended to be a subject to frequent change and thus use `typeof`

This functions accepts the object itself and 3 keys, but the problem is — I can't correctly infer types for all of them.

```ts
const theme = {
    button: { margin: { sm: "sm" } },
    form: { padding: { lg: "lg" } }
}

type Theme = typeof theme

type CompoName = keyof Theme;

// styles of component with give key
// { margin: ..., padding: ... }
type CompoStyle<C> = C extends CompoName ? keyof Theme[C] : never;

// string 
// S = margin, padding
type CompoStyleMod<C, S> = S extends keyof CompoStyle<C>
  ? CompoStyle<C>[S]
  : never;

const getStyle = (
    t: Theme,
    name: CompoName,
    style: CompoStyle<typeof name>,
    mod: CompoStyleMod<CompoName, typeof style>
) => {
    return t[name][style][mod]
}
```

The result of this in TypeScript 3.6.3:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"margin" | "padding"' can't be used to index type '{ margin: { sm: string; }; } | { padding: { lg: string; }; }'.

  Property 'margin' does not exist on type '{ margin: { sm: string; }; } | { padding: { lg: string; }; }'.
```

Looks like it is not possible to look up union types with union types and some kind of inference required midway.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBFAWBTAtomBeGBvAsAKBkJgCMBXKKcALmxmQEMAnAcwEswasYJkaAiHnxgBfEQBp8RGADMQjXrQAO9ACYr2zTjAA2mmH11DRw-Cbz4oAT0VoAKklQY41xCGlwHifPlCRYzRCgAZSttNEwAHkkiAGkYRAAPKEQwFQgYAGtESzcYexRECQIiIPiklLTM7Nz81ABtGIBdIqkAWTLk1PSsnPdaxAbGuqDG-AA+AAooGn6xGDB6VBoYuehLMJogueQQFRpWgEoMMbg6hdQhtbChnZVGgG5vPF9obmQnAODQxCnPOb4yBRwHx-gwWOwQfpBAd7jAAPRw7hQRgaHzgV66D6BELrH4IAr-WTySF8ZRqDQkwww+GI6AosDMIA) work for you?  I'm not sure why you've got those conditional types in there but my inclination would be to avoid them and go with generic lookups.

Comment: Oh, this looks much clearer then I expected! Ready to take this as correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be inclined to avoid all conditional types, since the compiler can't reason about them very well and it doesn't look like you need them.  Instead of `type Foo<T> = T extends U ? F<T> : never`, you could just [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T`, like `type Foo<T extends U> = Foo<T>`, which is more straightforward for the compiler.

The solution here is probably to make `getStyle()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in enough type parameters that the compiler understands that each parameter is drilling down into an object and [looking up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) its properties.  Like this:

```
const getStyle = <
    K extends keyof Theme,
    S extends keyof Theme[K],
    M extends keyof Theme[K][S]
>(t: Theme, name: K, style: S, mod: M) => t[name][style][mod];
```

Here we say that `t` is of type `Theme`, that `name` is of some generic type `K` constrained to `keyof Theme`, that `style` is of some generic type `S` constrained to `keyof Theme[K]`, and that `mod` is of some generic type `M` constrained to `keyof Theme[K][S]`.  That allows `t[name][style][mod]` to compile with no error, and the return type of `getStyle()` is inferred to be `Theme[K][S][M]`, meaning the output will be fairly strongly typed also:

```
const sm = getStyle(theme, "button", "margin", "sm"); // string
const lg = getStyle(theme, "form", "padding", "lg"); // string
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=63#code/MYewdgzgLgBFAWBTAtomBeGBvAsAKBkJgCMBXKKcALmxmQEMAnAcwEswasYJkaAiHnxgBfEQBp8RGADMQjXrQAO9ACYr2zTjAA2mmH11DRw-Cbz4oAT0VoAKklQY41xCGlwHifPlCRYzRCgAZSttNEwAHkkiAGkYRAAPKEQwFQgYAGtESzcYexRECQIiIPiklLTM7Nz81ABtGIBdIqkAWTLk1PSsnPdaxAbGuqDG-AA+AAooGn6xGDB6VBoYuehLMJogueQQFRpWgEoMMbg6hdQhtbChnZVGgG5vPF9obmQnAODQxCnPOb4yBRwHx-gwWOwQfpBAd7jAAPRw7hQRgaHzgV66D6BELrH4IAr-WTySF8ZRqDQkwww+GI6AosDMIA)