# Inferring types of non-leaf nodes of deeply nested object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I've been playing with [Inferring types of deeply nested object in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452055/inferring-types-of-deeply-nested-object-in-typescript).

Original code

```
const theme = {
    button: { margin: { sm: "sm" } },
    form: { padding: { sm: "sm1" } }
} as const;

type Theme = typeof theme;

const getStyle = <
    K extends keyof Theme,
    S extends keyof Theme[K],
    M extends keyof Theme[K][S]
>(t: Theme, name: K, style: S, mod: M) => t[name][style][mod];

getStyle(theme, 'button', 'margin', 'sm');
```

I have introduced one variation from the original example - in my code leaf nodes always have the same structure `{sm: string}`.

What I am struggling with is to modify `getStyle` in such way that the client can specify only 2  levels of keys, and benefit from the fact that the structure of the nodes is always the same;

```
const getStyleNew = <
    K extends keyof Theme,
    S extends keyof Theme[K]
>(t: Theme, name: K, style: S) => t[name][style].sm;
```

Unfortunately, this fails with:

```
Property 'sm' does not exist on type '{ readonly button: { readonly margin: { readonly sm: "sm"; }; }; readonly form: { readonly padding: { readonly sm: "sm"; }; }; }[K][S]'.
```

Is there a way to convince the compiler that sm is available on `t[name][style]` in the modified function?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFAWBTAtomBeGBvAUDfMARgK5RTgBc2MyAhgE4DmAlmFVjBMlQERc8wAvkIA0eAgDMQ9btQAOtACaLWjdp1l9kARgHDBOYbQgxQkKAG4cOKAE85aACpJUGOPcQgJcF4is4zaBhGRCgAZTsAGzRMAB5xfABpGEQADyhEMEUTAGtEWy8YZxREMQIYMJT0zOyYPILvYtQAbUSAXTKCAFkqjKzc-MKmxFa25rC2nAA%20AAooKmGRGDBaVCpEpehbaKowpeQQRSougEoMKbhmldQxreixg8U2-xDwqMQ53yWAchIycG%20PzoTFYgJg3y43xO-kCsFeEW2iAAcogAO5ueLlZJpPq1epDL4JCq9GoDBpFXyjaZzBZfZarRDrTbvXZndAXKBXBm3d5tAB0XAsQA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to assign the style record to an object with an `sm` property that is typed using a conditional `Index` type to account for possible absence of `sm`. This will even infer an exact literal type for the result instead of just `string`. Here's a generic solution, but you could also use `Theme` instead of `T`:

```
type Index<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : undefined;

const getStyleNew = <
  T,
  K extends keyof T,
  S extends keyof T[K]
>(t: T, name: K, style: S) => {
  const {sm}: {sm: Index<T[K][S], 'sm'>} = t[name][style]
  return sm
};

const test1 = getStyleNew(theme, 'button', 'margin'); // inferred: test1: "sm"
const test2 = getStyleNew(theme, 'form', 'padding'); // inferred: test2: "sm1"
```

If you query a styles record without an `sm` (e.g. `header: { fontSize: {} }`), the inferred type will be `undefined`:

```
const test3 = getStyleNew(theme, 'header', 'fontSize'); // inferred: test3: undefined
```

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution possible, but the `extends` clauses guarantee type safety on the keys, so it should be correct.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFAWBTAtomBeGBvAUDfMARgK5RTgBc2MyAhgE4DmAlmFVjBMlQERc8wAvkIA0eAgDMQ9btQAOtACaLWjdp1l9kARgHDBYgjCRLE9dVLBQAyswBeidvpzDaEGKEhQA3DhxQATzk0ABUkVAw4IMQQCThwxF8cT2gYRkQbQIAbNEwAHnF8AGkYRAAPKEQwRXcAa0QA2JgwlERDAmtSiqqamHrGuJbUAG0igF12-ABZLsrquoamocRRseHrMZwAPgAKKCplkRgwWlQqIqPoAJyqayPkEEUqKYBKDC24YZPUNauctYeijGSXSmWuiD2CSOAHISGRwNCYXQmKxETBoVxoS8koFgjAAJLVcp5EJHIofTAlcpzXr9JYwAD8zVWMCoxCJElYiEUSRSsFB1myiAAcogAO6RAr4UniKndeZ9RaDdqdak9BYDZnjbZ7A5Hb6OGAXThC25vdAfXD4PnYLiCdhcKiExTEkKrdYTdGYrbCTBQL6nRC-IWbfD0DLEehgDQuXngVKVaDaSICoWisWQ1owuHkMBo6HIlh57EwAD0pZgrAkZnDTzgiCTvH4yXjsETUAATCmMoLwenM6gYVIZPmFMpVFjvGWK1Wa9yqO2O02dDwW1569AAMzdsE5fsILPokwu+j5yw2eyISfTytgav0WsLhtQTdsjlcxQ4IA)