# How to infer type by nested object

Tags: typescript

Given the following sturcture:

```js
type Structure = {
  parent1: {
    child1_1: true,
    child1_2: true
  },
  parent2: {
    child2_1: true,
    child2_2: true
  }
}
```

I want to infer the following type:

```js
// Expected result: 
type FlattenedStructure = "parent1.child1_1" | "parent1.child1_2" | "parent2.child2_1" | "parent2.child2_2"
```

I tried to:

```js
// Expected result: type FlattenedStructure = "parent1.child1_1" | "parent1.child1_2" | "parent2.child2_1" | "parent2.child2_2"
type FlattenedStructure<T extends Structure = Structure> = {
  [parent in keyof T]: `${parent}.${keyof T[parent]}`
}[keyof T];


// I'm aware of this approach, but I'm not trying to do it this way
const getChild = <P extends keyof Structure, C extends keyof Structure[P]>(parent: P, child: C) => {
  return `${parent}.${child}` as const;
}

const b = getChild("parent2", "child2_1");
```

but it looks like I'm missing something. Autogenerate this combination would be the last resort if it's not possible.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-T4dcHYpYSqXABHWcWS6V0vayhXlW01NSVGlJDp6XJuuFAA)

PS - I'm aware of the question [Inferring types of deeply nested object in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452055/inferring-types-of-deeply-nested-object-in-typescript) but my use case is different.

Comment: You can use [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w26o1w) to get a union of dotted paths in an object type. See [the question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object) for more info.